# Why isn't the recursion code calling all the cases?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm currently a novice programmer learning recursion and I don't understand why my code isn't working. I have to write a recursion method called waysToClimb, which outputs the different methods to climb n steps. You can climb 1 or 2 steps in 1 stride. Here is what I have so far:

```
public void waysToClimb(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    //base case, makes a new line for the next series of steps 
    System.out.println();
  }
  if (n >= 1) {
    //1 step, prints 1 and subtracts 1 from n
    System.out.print("1 ");
    waysToClimb(n - 1);
  }
  if (n >= 2) {
    //2 steps, prints 2 and subtracts 2 from n
    System.out.print("2 ");
    waysToClimb(n - 2);
  }
}
```

My problem is that when the amount of steps is greater than 2, the if statement for when `n >= 2` outputs only a 2, but no other numbers. For example, the case waysToClimb(3) prints out:

```
1 1 1  
2 (should be 1 2)  
2 1
```

Why doesn't it print out 1 2? Shouldn't the if statements I had print out all possible combinations, since the code is forced to check every single one

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to check why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labeling your code and stepping it through:

```
public void waysToClimb(int n) {
  // #1
  if (n == 0) {   
    //base case, makes a new line for the next series of steps 
    System.out.println();
  }
  // #2
  if (n >= 1) {
    //1 step, prints 1 and subtracts 1 from n
    System.out.print("1 ");
    waysToClimb(n - 1);
  }
  // #3
  if (n >= 2) {
    //2 steps, prints 2 and subtracts 2 from n
    System.out.print("2 ");
    waysToClimb(n - 2);
  }
}
```

What your code does now step-by-step:

```
Call:          IF:    Print:      Function call:
waysToClimb(3) #2     1           waysToClimb(2)
waysToClimb(2) #2     1           waysToClimb(1)
waysToClimb(1) #2     1           waysToClimb(0)
waysToClimb(0) #1     \n          return
waysToClimb(2) #3     2           waysToClimb(0)
waysToClimb(0) #1     \n          return
waysToClimb(3) #3     2           waysToClimb(1)
waysToClimb(1) #2     1           waysToClimb(0)
waysToClimb(0) #1     \n          return
```

Thus the output is :

```
1 1 1
2
2 1
```

What you should do:

```
public void waysToClimb(int n, String s) {
  if (n == 0) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
  if (n >= 1) {
    waysToClimb(n - 1, s + "1 ");
  }
  if (n >= 2) {
    waysToClimb(n - 2, s + "2 ");
  }
}
```

Call the function with:

```
 waysToClimb(3, "");
```

Comment: Oh... I think I see why it started at 2 after it finished the first waysToClimb(0). After it was done with the first case when it starts to unravel back up it checks if 2 >= 2 and it starts there instead of 3. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Call stack is:

```
waysToClimb(3)
  System.out.print("1 ")
  waysToClimb(2)
    System.out.print("1 ")
    waysToClimb(1)
      System.out.print("1 ")
      waysToClimb(0)
        System.out.println()
    System.out.print("2 ")
    waysToClimb(0)
      System.out.println()
  System.out.print("2 ")
  waysToClimb(1)
    System.out.print("1 ")
    waysToClimb(0)
      System.out.println()
```